# EXTRACT PORTION OF STRING IN A CELL

Tags: ms-access

I would like to extract string after an "_".

Here is my data:

```
data                       
3CC1P01_1 1/2"_ST 25_B31.3
```

And Desired output should be like this:

```
data                         c1       c2       c3       c4
3CC1P01_1 1/2"_ST 25_B31.3   3CC1P01  1 1/2"   ST 25    B31.3
```

Comment: Please [do not post images of code or data](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) - you are forcing people willing to help you to re-type your data/code to test and provide you a solution.

Comment: This is noted. thanks for the advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String manipulation functions Left, Mid, InStr, InStrRev can easily extract C1 and C4. Gets complicated for the other parts. Build a VBA function.

```
Function GetString(strS As String, intP As Integer) As String
Dim strAry As Variant
strAry = Split(strS, "_")
GetString = strAry(intP - 1)
End Function
```

Call function from query or textbox for each of the desired parts.
`GetString([fieldname], 1)`